# ID Field Skipping Numbers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, id

In the last few weeks in one of my lists, the ID field appears to have started skipping numbers. (I'm trying to confirm with the users that there isn't actually a missing list item and it's just a weird system behavior.) I've looked in the recycle bin (both the "end user recycle bin" items and the "deleted from end user recycle bin" views). I haven't seen this happen at all before (and it's been several years that this particular list has been having items added, current max item ID is about 3950) and am wondering if this is normal and if there's an explanation for it.

Comment: Since that field doesn't skip numbers, it sounds like some items have been deleted.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to find the items that were deleted? Or to find out if someone actually did delete them?

Comment: If you have Site Collection Auditing with the Delete option enabled, you can pull those logs. If you don't, you can do a query on the EventCache table in the Content Database... which isn't preferred, of course.